# JSON error while using Pandas output format

Tags: alpha-vantage

I am using alpha_vantage Timeseries API like below:

-----------------------------------------code------------------------------------

```
    import pandas as pd
    from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
    from alpha_vantage.techindicators import TechIndicators
    from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from pprint import pprint
    #my key
    key = 'mykey'
    ts = TimeSeries(key, output_format='pandas')

    def processMyBatch(batch, FD):
        for i in batch:
            df, meta_data = ts.get_quote_endpoint(i)
            FD=FD.append(df)
        return(FD)    

    main code...
    for i in batches:
        DF2=processMyBatch(i, DF)
        DF=DF2
```

---

While the API worked for few symbols (see error log below), somewhere in between going through the list of symbols, I suddenly got the following JSONDecoder error ... but I am using output_format as pandas. Could you please throw some light on why this error occurred?

thank you

================error===============

```
    /opt/scripts
    starting now. fileName is:  /mnt/NAS/Documents/../../../dailyquote2020-03-03.xlsx
    completed the batch: ['AAPL', 'ABBV', 'AMZN', 'BAC', 'BNDX']
    Waiting to honor API requirement: for  1 min
    Waited: 65 sec
    completed the batch: ['C', 'CNQ', 'CTSH', 'EEMV', 'FBGRX']
    Waiting to honor API requirement: for  1 min
    Waited: 65 sec
    completed the batch: ['FDVV', 'FFNOX', 'FSMEX', 'FXAIX', 'GE']
    Waiting to honor API requirement: for  1 min
    Waited: 65 sec
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "getQuotes.py", line 55, in <module>
        DF2=processMyBatch(i, DF)
      File "getQuotes.py", line 29, in processMyBatch
        df, meta_data = ts.get_quote_endpoint(i)
      File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alpha_vantage/alphavantage.py", line 174, in _format_wrapper
        self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alpha_vantage/alphavantage.py", line 159, in _call_wrapper
        return self._handle_api_call(url), data_key, meta_data_key
      File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alpha_vantage/alphavantage.py", line 287, in _handle_api_call
        json_response = response.json()
      File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
        return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
        return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
    simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Added on 3/4/2020

```
..
..

completed the batch: ['FDVV', 'FFNOX', 'FSMEX', 'FXAIX', 'GE']
Waiting to honor API requirement: for  1 min
Waited: 65 sec
completed the batch: ['GOOGL', 'IGEB', 'IJH', 'IJR', 'IMTB']
Waiting to honor API requirement: for  1 min
Waited: 65 sec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getQuotes.py", line 55, in <module>
    DF2=processMyBatch(i, DF)
..

..
```

Comment: This script is running as a daily cron job. Interestingly the script processed one more batch today before failing with the same error code - see above I have edited the error section

Answer (score 1):

Well I was getting an error like that today and it turns out the Alpha Vantage site is down!